# undefined reference to 'main' when compiling

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

Possible dup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225076/strange-compiler-error-undefined-reference-to-main) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965437/undefined-reference-to-main-collect2-ld-returned-1-exit-status), but even after trying to dig through the answers for a while, I couldn't resolve this.

While trying to compile following makefile,

```
all:  test

    test:  constants.h Point.h Point.cpp line_t.h line_t.cpp drawing_t.h drawing_t.cpp clipper_t.h clipper_t.cpp main.cpp
        g++ -o test Point.cpp line_t.cpp drawing_t.cpp clipper_t.cpp main.cpp -lglut
```

I get an error:

> g++ -o test Point.cpp line_t.cpp drawing_t.cpp clipper_t.cpp main.cpp
>   -lglut /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start': (.text+0x18): undefined reference to`main'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [test] Error 1

I am new at Makefile. I guess, I am missing something too obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently none your files define a function with the signature

```
int main();
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

Comment: Found it!
I had declared main like..
namespace std{
int main(){
...
}
}.

Replacing with..
using namespace std;
.. done the trick!

Comment: @powerpravin Introducing names into the namespace `std` is not allowed. It can lead to really messed up results.